# deploying laravel error on shared host

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, deployment

I am deploying my laravel 5.4 project on a shared host using subdomain
I installed composer, changed paths of index.php , vendor paths , DB host, username , etc..

I am getting the following error

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: There is no existing directory at "/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied in 
 /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:171

I tried the following commands :
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ -R

but (composer dump-autoload ) gives an error because php -v is 5 although I am choosing it to be 7 in the cpanel

I tried also setenforce 0

but nothing happened .. can any one help please??

Comment: did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 1):

php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

works for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Duplicate of: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703945/500-server-error-when-deploying-laravel-app-in-aws/66635620#66635620)

1. Check in laravel root folder your `.env` file :

a) Check if you have `.env` file , if not copy-paste `.env.example` to `.env`

b) `APP_DEBUG = true` (when deploying to a server, after checking your app - change on false)

c) `APP_KEY =`  (these must be empty)

d) Save `.env` file

e) Run `php artisan key:generate`

f) Open your website (all another errors server return)

2. Run `composer install`

---

This is my solution for apache2 on Ubuntu 20.4

I assume you already did the Steps from phwt & Taras. These are still necessary.

You need to change:

- `ServerName` to your IP Address or Domain
- `DocumentRoot` to the Path to your public Laravel directory
- `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =` to your IP Address or Domain

File: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mylaravelproject.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public/

   <Directory /var/www/laravel/public/>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mylaravelproject.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

After Saving this run:

```
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

(Optional, **but** recommended) If you want to use an SSL Cert do:
`sudo certbot`
and follow the instructions