# 500 Server Error when deploying laravel app in aws

Tags: laravel, server

I have been trying to resolve this error for 2 weeks but have not resolve yet.

I have used all answers related to this issue but have not find any suitable solution for my problem :(

used commands

```
chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/storage
sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_blog
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage
```

Please help me ||

Comment: A 500 error can be cause by hundreds of reasons which you have already figured out by the sounds of it :) Check the logs of your webserver and the laravel logs in `storage/logs` to figure out the error message which could help finding the solution and/or help us help you.

Comment: sir you can see logs and please help me in figure out the solution https://pastebin.com/ujvrPMxT

Comment: Please can you show a screenshot of the error screen.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QpkBbxT

Comment: I think you need to check the PHP error logs and the Laravel error logs to get to the bottom of this. I am not seeing the actual error here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check in laravel root folder your `.env` file :

   a) Check if you have `.env` file , if not copy-paste `.env.example` to `.env`

   b) `APP_DEBUG = true` (when deploying to a server, after checking your app - change on false)

   c) `APP_KEY =` (these must be empty)

   d) Save `.env` file

   e) Run `php artisan key:generate`

   f) Open your website (all another errors server return)
2. Run `composer install`

Comment: b)APP_DEBUG = true (when deploying to server , after checking your app - change on false) helped me to see errors

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for apache2 on Ubuntu 20.4

I assume you already did the Steps from phwt & Taras. These are still necessary.

You need to change:

- `ServerName` to your IP Address or Domain
- `DocumentRoot` to the Path to your public Laravel directory
- `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =` to your IP Address or Domain

File: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mylaravelproject.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public/

   <Directory /var/www/laravel/public/>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mylaravelproject.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

After Saving this run:

```
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

(Optional, **but** recommended) If you want to use an SSL Cert do:
`sudo certbot`
and follow the instructions